# ERROR In Sequences query if postgres

Tags: postgresql

I create one sequence in postgres and fire one query which is mentioned below

```
SELECT M_PRODUCTSEQ.NEXTVAL from DUAL;
```

but it gives me the below error:

> ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist.

Kindly help me out. How can i made the relation with dual?

Comment: Check the manual, everything is documented there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does NOT support the `from DUAL` syntax. It does however make the `from` portion of a query like this optional, so getting the next value (`nextval`) of a sequence you would do something like this:

```
SELECT nextval('m_productseq');
```

Comment: if i written as you metioned it gives error
missing FROM-clause entry for table "m_productseq"

Comment: still it giving error
 column "m_productseq" does not exist

Comment: I added the '', try now.

Comment: Still it is giving same error
is there anything like "synonym" for the sequence in postgre

Comment: Can you please post the error that you get by executing: `SELECT nextval('m_productseq');`

Comment: column "M_PRODUCTSEQ" does not exist

Comment: Are you sure that this sequence exist?